# how to create a slide like the following?

Tags: beamer

everyone. So, I was just wondering, does anyone know how to create a slide like this using Latex, maybe beamer presentation? Or maybe it was created using PowerPoint?

**EDIT:** I have used beamer earlier and I just do not know how to create a slide like this. More specifically, the red part and the overall layout? What I have used about beamer is the simple and classic one. Like the other picture. [image]
[image: a screenshot excerpt from the video lecture of MIT opencourseware]

Comment: Welcome, right now, this question is too broad and cannot be answered. You can create slides with LaTeX, one class specialising in that is called `beamer`.

Comment: This is not a we-do-it-for-you-site. It is possible to create this in beamer. But you should try to do it and ask here if you encounter problems you can not solve on your own.

Comment: I have used beamer earlier. Sorry for not making it clear. I just have never seen situations like this.

Comment: There are many tools that you can use to make such a presentation. If you want to do it with `beamer`, start doing it. When you get stuck at some point, not knowing how to achieve a certain effect, feel free to ask again.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by `situations like this`? This slide can be done in beamer, but to avoid useless work, it would be nice to know what element you are interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`torino` theme](https://github.com/bbatsov/beamer-torino-theme) you can get close enough to fulfil the the vagueness of your question.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[titleline]{Torino}

\definecolor{chameleongreen3}{named}{gray}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\author{Marco Barisione}
\title{Torino, a pretty theme for \LaTeX{} Beamer}
\institute{Politecnico di Torino}
\date{September 18, 2007}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,fragile]{How to use the theme}
\begin{itemize}
\item Install Beamer
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Some distros have a \verb!latex-beamer! \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\alert{package}} \rotatebox{30}{\tiny \alert{some text}}
  \end{itemize}
\item Read the Beamer documentation
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \verb!/usr/share/doc/latex-beamer/beameruserguide.pdf.gz! if you are
        using Debian
  \item \verb!doc/beameruserguide.pdf! in the source package
  \end{itemize}
\item Install the theme
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \verb!mkdir -p ~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer!\\
  \item \verb!cp *.sty ~/texmf/tex/latex/beamer!
  \end{itemize}
\item Read the example files
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \verb!chameleon.tex!: green theme, watermark and circles for bullet
        lists
  \item \verb!nouvelle.tex!: green and red theme, watermark and squares for
        bullet lists
  \item \verb!freewilly.tex!: blue theme, a logo and squares for bullet lists
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]